# Where can I check my neovim lua 'runtimepath'?

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm new to neovim (or vim) settings and I was trying to require '.lua' file but failed.

This is my directory structure.

```
~/.config/nvim
 ├ init.vim
 ├ /lua
   ├ basic.lua
```

and these are my codes.

~/.config/nvim/init.vim

```
lua require('basic')
```

~/.config/nvim/lua/basic.lua

```lua
print('hello from basic.lua')
```

and error logs (My system is M2 MacOS)

```
E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: module 'basic' not found:
        no field package.preload['basic']
        no file './basic.lua'
        no file '/opt/homebrew/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/basic.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/basic.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/basic/init.lua'
        no file '/opt/homebrew/share/lua/5.1/basic.lua'
        no file '/opt/homebrew/share/lua/5.1/basic/init.lua'
        no file './basic.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/basic.so'
        no file '/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.1/basic.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
```

I found that I can requiring like `require('lua.basic')` runs okay.
So I'm assuming that '~/.config/nvim' is contained in `runtimepath`.

But how can I check my lua `runtimepath` and modify it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get your current runtimepath via Neovim API with `nvim_list_runtime_paths()` function :

`:lua print(vim.inspect(vim.api.nvim_list_runtime_paths()))`

Comment: Thanks so much. I've checked current runtimepath and added this line to my init.vim and it worked fine.
`let &runtimepath.=', "~/.config/nvim/lua"'`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the full runtime path, my neovim is loading lua modules from a folder that is not present in `vim.api.nvim_list_runtime_paths()`.

Comment: If it helps anyone, I found out that `lazy.nvim` changed the `runtimepath` with a slight delay. So my init script was able to import the module from the "default" `runtimepath` and shortly after `lazy.nvim` changed `runtimpath` but the pesky module has already been loaded.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I think the following fixed it: I removed the `init.vim` and am now using an `init.lua` with the following content:

```
vim.api.nvim_command('set runtimepath^=~/.vim')
vim.api.nvim_command('let &packpath = &runtimepath')
vim.api.nvim_command('source ~/.vim/vimrc')
```

Suddenly, `require` works as expected!

Answer (score 2):

I think something must be messed up. Sourcing lua files from your config directory should just work. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to debug that.

But here is a way you could set your rtp using lua

```lua
lua vim.opt.runtimepath:append(',~/.config/nvim/lua')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, on windows it should be `vim.opt.runtimepath:append([[,%localappdata%\nvim\lua]])`

Answer (score 0):

you can add `vim.o.path = vim.o.path .. './lua'` in lua file